# "squares.splice is not function" Is there any reason for this error?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have followed a tutorial from freeCodeCamp (link here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAUn1Lom6dw). At the time 1:26:00 they use a **.`splice`** on a  **variable squares array.** I am new to JavaScript. The `splice` method is used in the addScore function which is called in the freeze function. I have read that this error usually occurs if used on string but that shouldn't be the case.

Is there any way to fix this error?
Code below.
**app.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const grid = document.querySelector('.grid')
    let squares = document.querySelectorAll('.grid div')
    
    //function draw
    function draw(){
        current.forEach(index => {
                squares[currentPosition + index].classList.add('tetromino')
                squares[currentPosition + index].classList.add(colors[randomColor])
                //document.getElementsByClassName("tetromino")[index].style.background = colors[randomColor]
        })
    }
    
    //draw()
    
    function undraw(){
        current.forEach(index => {
            squares[currentPosition + index].classList.remove('tetromino')
            squares[currentPosition + index].classList.remove(colors[randomColor])
        })
    }

    /* timerId= setInterval(moveDown, 1000) */
    document.addEventListener('keyup',control)
    function moveDown(){
        undraw()
        currentPosition += width
        draw()
        freeze()
    }

    //freeze
    function freeze(){
        if(current.some(index => squares[currentPosition + index + width].classList.contains('taken'))){
            current.forEach(index => squares[currentPosition + index].classList.add('taken'))
            random = nextRandom
            randomColor = nextCol
            nextRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*theTetrominos.length)
        
            current = theTetrominos[random][currentRotation]
            nextCol = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)
        
            currentPosition = 4
            draw()
            displayShape()
            addScore()
        }
    }

    function addScore(){
        for(let i=0; i < 199; i+=width){
            const row = [i ,i+1,i+2,i+3,i+4,i+5,i+6,i+7,i+8,i+9]
        
            if(row.every(index => squares[index].classList.contains('taken'))){
                score+=10
                scoreDisplay.innerHTML = score
                row.forEach(index => {
                    squares[index].classList.remove('taken')
                    squares[index].classList.remove(colors[0])
                    squares[index].classList.remove(colors[1])
                    squares[index].classList.remove(colors[2])
                    squares[index].classList.remove(colors[3])
                    squares[index].classList.remove(colors[4])
                })
            
                const squaresRemoved = squares.splice(i, width)
                console.log(squaresRemoved)
                squares =squaresRemoved.concat(squares)
                squares.forEach(cell => grid.appendChild(cell))
            }
        }
    }
})
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en' dir='ltr'>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' charset='utf-8'></link>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>Basic Tetris</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Score:<span id='score'>0</span></h3>
        <button id='start-button'>Start/Pause</button>
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='grid'>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                ...
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div class='taken'></div>
                <div class='taken'></div>
                <div class='taken'></div>
                <div class='taken'></div>
                <div class='taken'></div>
                <div class='taken'></div>
                <div class='taken'></div>
                <div class='taken'></div>
                <div class='taken'></div>
                <div class='taken'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='mini-grid'>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src='app.js' charset='utf-8'></script>
    </body>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Reduce your question to include only relevant code. Css isn't relevant for JavaScript errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList, you should convert it to an array to use array methods use

```
 Array.prototype.slice.call(squares)
```

or

```
var squares= Array.from(squares)
```

Comment: You can also do `const squares = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.grid div'));`

Comment: @StackSlave Yes that's possible to I didn't mention it because some may consider it as bad practice although, I personally don't see any problem in doing it that way. Please feel free to include it in the answer if you want to :)

Comment: No problem. I voted you up. This should be good enough for the accepted answer, but I don't know why you want to pass `i` and `width`.

Answer (score 1):

querySelectorAll() returns a NodeList. Try this

```
Array.from(squares).splice(...)
```

or after you define square, code:

```
square = Array.from(square)
```

Answer (score 0):

querySelectorAll returns a NodeList not an Array. NodeLists do not have a splice method.